# Calculate limit of $\sqrt[n]{2^n - n}$

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

Calculate limit of $\sqrt[n]{2^n - n}$.
I know that lim $\sqrt[n]{2^n - n} \le 2$, but don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT:

- $\sqrt[n]{2^n-2^{n-1}}\leq\sqrt[n]{2^n-n}\leq\sqrt[n]{2^n}$
- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n}{n}}=2^1=2$
- $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n-2^{n-1}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{2^{n-1}}
  =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2^{\frac{n-1}{n}}=2^{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n-1}{n}}=2^1=2$

Comment: Wow, that was far simpler than i thought. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CsabaZsolnai: You're welcome :)

Comment: Why the down vote?????

Comment: @barakmanos That's the same I was going to ask. `:(`

Comment: @barakmanos  I was about to ask you the same question.

Comment: @egreg: I've got a feeling it's one of users below (neither of whom did I down-vote myself).

Comment: @MichaelCotton: I've got a feeling it's one of users below (neither of whom did I down-vote myself).

Answer (score 0):

The exponential function is continuous, so $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n -n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} e^{\frac{\ln(2^n-n)}{n}} = e^{(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(2^n-n)}{n})}$$

Then you could use l'Hospital to show that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln(2^n-n)}{n} = \ln(2)$$

So then you'd have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{2^n -n} = e^{\ln(2)} = 2$$

Comment: You could simply edit your previous answer, rather than deleting it and adding a new one.

Comment: @egreg I only wanted to make a strong hint. So I didn't want a complete answer to appear in the edit history.

Comment: My original answer had worked out the middle limit. But that was giving too much away.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:
$\sqrt[n]{2^n - n} = 2 (1 - \frac{n}{2^n})^{\frac{1}{n}} = 2 ((1 - \frac{n}{2^n})^{\frac{2^n}{n}} )^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$

Now... Do you know Euler?